# Convert row to format matching index

Tags: python, pandas, loops, datetime

1. I have a df of shape 3000,125
2. The first row of my df represents bond tickers
3. The 2nd row represents the date they were sold
4. My index is a historical time series, and the values within the df represent the daily stock prices
   e.g

   ```
                   AAPL         GOOGLE         IBM
                 16/02/2018  15/03/2022   22/08/2020

   2019/jan/02  5             4              3
   2019/jan/03. 4             4              4
   2019/jan/04. 4             4              5
   2019/jan/05  3             5              2 
   2012/Mar/03  10            20             22
   ```

I would like to run a loop on the values however to do so, the index and `df.iloc[0]` aka the first row needs to be in the same format.

I was able to convert the index to datetime format using the following code w/o issue:

```
  dftest2.index =  pd.to_datetime(dftest2.index, format='%Y%m%d')
```

Problem statement is that I'd like to convert the first row of the df to match the index format. The first row is in string format in the form `'%d/%m/Y%'`) however in order for it to match the index it needs to be in `'%Y%m%d'`.

I've used the following code in order for it to match the date format of the index:

```
dftest2.iloc[0] = pd.to_datetime(dftest2.iloc[0]).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

And running the below code also produces the following error:

```
dftest2.iloc[0] = pd.to_datetime(dftest2.iloc[0]).datetime.strptime('%Y-%m-%d')
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'datetime'
```

Stuck on how to convert this now into to datetime format matching index. Previous attempts to convert to datetime have resulted in the row being converted into int format with nonsensical numbers, 187745300000 etc.

How do i convert the row to match the index. The error I am getting now when running the loop is:

```
 TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'numpy.ndarray' and 'str'
```

I've looked all over stackoverflow for possible variations of  my problem but w/o success.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you just want to turn the first row into a datetime object to do some further operations?

if so, this worked for me -

```
test_ = pd.to_datetime(df.iloc[0].str.replace("*", "").str.replace(".", ""))
print(test_)

AAPL     2017-04-01
Google   2021-02-03
IBM      2020-03-03
Name: 0, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

if you pass the `.strftime` method you will end up with an object.

hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you. When running the above code i got the following error msg: ValueError: value must be an integer, received <class 'str'> for year

Comment: there must be more items you need to replace, you can add an argument in datetime to coerce the outliers into NaT `pd.to_datetime(date, errors='coerce')` however I used your data and it worked for me.